# Angular 6 ngrx Why selector get object with superfluous property?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have an selectror     `export const selectConversations = (state: any): Conversation[] => {.....};`

This is store interface

```
    export interface ChatStore {
    participants: { [key: number]: User };
    conversations: { [key: number]: Conversation };
    messages: { [key: number]: Message };
}
```

This is how i register reducer     `StoreModule.forRoot({
      data: chatReducer
    })`

This is reducer

```
export function chatReducer(state: ChatStore = INITIAL_CHAT_STORE_DATA, action: ChatActions.Actions): ChatStore {...}
```

This is function inside my reducer

```
export function handleLoadCompleteConversations(state: ChatStore, action: LoadCompleteConversations): ChatStore {
    const newStoreState = _.cloneDeep(state);
    newStoreState.conversations = _.keyBy(action.payload, 'id');
    console.log('newStoreState', newStoreState);
    return newStoreState;
}
```

The problem is in my selector comes object like

```
       { data: {
    participants: { [key: number]: User };
    conversations: { [key: number]: Conversation };
    messages: { [key: number]: Message };
}}
```

where does property         `data`    was added? after all there is no that property inside store interface         `ChatStore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `data` property here:

```
 StoreModule.forRoot({
  data: chatReducer // <----- data points to chatReducer which returns state object.
})
```

You need to look on chatReducer as a object which it is. If you don't want to have 
'data' property then all you need is

```
 StoreModule.forRoot(chatReducer).
```

Comment: so why in my reducer's  `handleLoadCompleteConversations` function  comes object like `ChatStore` without data property?

Answer (score 1):

Because you introduced one more object level by pointing to to 'data'

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  data: chatReducer <-- here
})
```

change to this

```
StoreModule.forRoot(chatReducer)
```

You need to modify you selector to select sub state

```
export const selectConversations = (state: any) => state.conversations;
```

Using this you need to create your sub-selectors ( giving an example )

```
export const selectFirstTenConversations = createSelector(
  selectConversations, conversations => conversations.slice(0,10) 
);
```

Comment: ok, but why in `handleLoadCompleteConversations` comes object like `{
    participants: { [key: number]: User };
    conversations: { [key: number]: Conversation };
    messages: { [key: number]: Message };
}` without `data` ? i call selector this way `this.store.select(selectConversations);`

Comment: because you are assigning the entire state to newStoreState to handleLoadCompleteConversations and printing it. so you will get all state informations